# granting a single client rw access to an NFS-subdirectory, while others have a more restricted access

Tags: debian, nfs, nfsv4

So I have an NFS-server that exports a large share to the entire network.
One of the clients requires *write-access* as *root* to a subdirectory of the share.
This client only requires access to that subdirectory (and I don't want to grant the client full access to the other exports).
I don't want to grant the same privileges to the other hosts.

So after a bit of fiddling I came up with the following `/etc/exports` file:

```
/media/DATA         192.168.0.0/24(ro,fsid=0,no_subtree_check)
/media/DATA/photos  192.168.0.30(rw,fsid=0,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
```

As you can see there are (at least) two peculiarities:

- the same directory (`/media/DATA/photos`) is exported twice for the host `192.168.0.30` (by virtue of `192.168.0.30` being a subset of `192.168.0.0/24`, and `/media/DATA/photos` being a subdirectory of `/media/DATA`)
- there are two exports with `fsid=0`

This works, as I can now do:

- on `192.168.0.99` run `mount nfsserver:/ /mnt` and I will get *ro* access (with root-squashing) to the `nfsserver:/media/DATA/` directory
- on `192.168.0.30` run `mount nfsserver:/ /mnt` and I will get *rw* access (even as *root*!) to the `nfsserver:/media/DATA/photo/` directory

yay!

However: is this guaranteed to work?

I have not found any documentation on what happens if two exports both get the `fsid=0` option.
Which one will take precedence?

Also: I would be happy to not re-root the export for 192.168.0.30 to `/media/DATA/photos` (si I would need mount `nfsserver:/photos`). But changing the line to `/media/DATA/photos 192.168.0.30(rw,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)` drops the *rw* and *no_root_squash* options.

sidenote: I've found a 7 year old [Redhat support question](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/107793) that is supposed to deal with this issue.
But since I'm on Debian and don't plan to switch to Redhat anytime soon, I have no intentions of buying a subscription for this single question)